# ccny_rgbd rviz configuration files in .rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, ccny-rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Im running ubuntu 12.10 with ROS groovy. Trying to use ccny_rgbd I couldnt use any of the rviz configuration files because they are in .vcg files! Anyone has the new .rviz files? Is there an easy translation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60527/ccny_rgbd-rviz-configuration-files-in-.rviz?/) by [fersarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3210/fersarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They have now  added the configuration files for groovy here https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_rgbd_tools/blob/groovy/ccny_rgbd/launch/vo%2Bmapping.rviz

---

Originally posted by [fersarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3210/fersarr/) with karma: 57 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sigmaduarte](https://answers.ros.org/users/7181/sigmaduarte/) on 2013-10-25**:
how do you load those config? what comand line did you use?